# Mobile number validation

Tags: mobile, validation, logic

I am trying to find best way to validate a mobile number with in a country.

Currently my understanding is: User can enter whatever format they want in mobile numbers and its a waste of time and energy to validate it against a set of regular expressions.

My application is not a critical one like banking application and if the user is entering an invalid mobile number, it is at his own risk to get updates (like activate account/ do something with the application)

So I think the best way is to check for mobile number length and whether all are digits.

I want to know the best way forward and is there any good resource (non-scattered) to get all mobile number length validations based on a country code?

Comment: eh, mobile numbers (like phone numbers) are very country specific, your best bet would be sending a message for validation

Comment: Checking that all are digits will fail if the user enters "+44123456789" as their number.

Comment: yup country specific, is there some resource of validating using length?

Comment: @chrisF see thats what exactly was talking about, I don't want to  complicate my code accepting the wishes of user. Sending validation message to mobile is not a cost effective solution and polluting the code with all regex is in my opinion a waste of time. I can always trim down the + or whatever special characters.

Comment: Check out [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/): a library for handling phone numbers (made by Google, btw).

Comment: Go with @JoachimSauer's suggestion. I just tested it and it's accurate - even tells you if the number is for a mobile or a landline. Use libphonumber and add a validation text message. That should do the job.

Comment: sadly mine is a windows mobile app and I cant port it because it is using some native google dll :(

Comment: Well then check for length and standard prefixes, and augment that with a validation text message. Seems like the simplest way to go.

Comment: @RohithNair - Check out the [source view](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk) for the different languages that aren't available in the binary download section. It has both C++ and JavaScript source libraries that you can use, as well as information on how to use them.

Comment: Time to start a business doing the telephony equivalent of PO boxes...

Answer (score 3):

Dealing with phone numbers it not trivial. Every country has their own specification.

Examples of variations (for each country):

1. The area code length can vary
2. The mobile phone area codes are different
3. The native format is different

You could of course force the usage of E.164 (`+<countrycode><areacode><number>`) but that doesn't feel very user friendly. You can not just strip all white spaces and just add a `+` and think that it's E.164. For instance Swedish phone numbers should be stripped of a leading `0` in the area code when converting to E.164.

To make a long story short: It's pointless to validate mobile phone numbers by yourself.

Options:

1. Send a SMS to the phone containing a code (two step validation)
2. Use an existing phone number library
3. Get the number plan for every country. (Swedens can be found here: http://www.pts.se/en-GB/Industry/Telephony/Numbering/National-numbering-and-addressing-plans/The-international-public-telecommunication-numbering-plan-E164/)

Comment: UK numbers need the leading `0` stripping and replacing by `+44` (the country code) as well. I was going to suggest it was true worldwide, but I'm willing to bet that there are a few that don't follow that rule.

Comment: @ChrisF: US numbers do not have a leading zero (if we can believe in movies ;))

Comment: He, he. True. Don't their codes start with a 1? So what would be an "0800" number in the UK would be a "1800" number in the US.

Comment: No. 1 is their country code, as 44 is the one for UK.

Comment: @ChrisF:  The leading `0` in UK numbers (and those of many other countries) is a local convention called a _trunk prefix_ that's only used inside the country.  The North American Numbering Plan's trunk prefix is `1`, which can cause some confusion because the country code for that dialing plan is also `1`.  So just as you don't dial `+1 1 202 456 1111` to reach the White House from London, you don't dial `+44 0 20 7930 4832` to reach Buckingham Palace from Washington.  Once all NANP areas have switched to ten-digit dialing, the trunk prefix in the US can die off with no ill effects.

Comment: @ChrisF - Also (FWIW), a "1-800" number can also be (and has, recently, been) reduced to simply "800". Depending on your phone plan, you can omit the "1" entirely (some telecomm systems still require the country code when calling long distance, but it's becoming increasingly rare). This is because our phone numbers are standardized to "xxx-xxx-xxxx", and "800" is simply a reserved "area code" for toll-free numbers.

Comment: @Shauna - ah! I see now. So in the US there's no equivalent to the leading "0" we have in the UK.

Comment: @ChrisF - A quick little bit of research says that's only partially correct. I think we Americans don't see it as a trunk prefix, because our country code is also 1, but, like what Blrfl said, the US does have a trunk prefix. So, technologically/officially, there is an equivalent ("1"), but conceptually, not really, because our trunk prefix and country code happen to be the same, and because it can currently be omitted entirely when calling (to use the above example, I can simply dial `202 456 1111` to reach the White House).